# Disabling a startup service

Tags: linux, debian, debian-squeeze

I am using `insserv -r nfs-common` to disable RPC. How do I know if it worked? Is there a way to list the services starting up? Is it supposed to disappear from `/etc/init.d` (because it still there)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I know if it worked?

After rebooting, look at `ps auxw | grep rpc.statd`, if you see it as a running process it's still running.

> is there a way to list the services starting up?

This is one way...

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ grep initdefault /etc/inittab
id:2:initdefault:
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

From this, I know run-level 2 is the level the machine boots into... now look at `/etc/rc2.d`

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ ls /etc/rc2.d
K01gdm3            S02dbus           S03apache2          S06bootlogs
README             S02fail2ban       S04avahi-daemon     S06samba
S01binfmt-support  S02loadcpufreq    S04bluetooth        S14portmap
S01fancontrol      S02lwresd         S04cpufrequtils     S15nfs-common
S01rsyslog         S02ntp            S04cron             S16nfs-kernel-server
S01sudo            S02openbsd-inetd  S04exim4            S17rc.local
S02acpid           S02smartmontools  S04kerneloops       S17rmnologin
S02anacron         S02snmpd          S04network-manager  S17stop-bootlogd
S02atd             S02ssh            S05cups
S02bind9           S02winbind        S05saned
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

Anything that has an "S" at the beginning is started at boot. Anything with a "K" at the beginning does not start at boot.

> Is it supposed to disappear from /etc/init.d (because it still there)?

All the startup scripts symlink to `/etc/init.d`, so the rpc startup script should still be there.  Look at `/etc/rcX.d` to know for sure

Comment: I don't understand the "levels". Could you explain to me why there are levels and what each one does?

Comment: Run levels are a way to keep multiple boot "configurations" available on your box.  Typically I have a run-level for a graphical login and another for a text login, although it's really up to you whether you use more than one (or what you keep configured in each run level).  This [DebianHelp article](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/runlevels.htm) will do a better job than I would describing run levels from scratch

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing *rcconf* via aptitude. It lists services that are started on boot. Rcconf will list all installed services -- services that start on boot are clearly marked. To run *rcconf* simply run *rcconf* as root.

Answer (score 1):

**chkconfig** method

For the height of laziness / efficiency, you can also use [`chkconfig`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/chkconfig8.html)

To see how `portmap`, `nfs-common`, and `nfs-kernel-server` are used at all runlevels...

```
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$ sudo chkconfig --list | grep -Ei "nfs|portmap"
mountkernfs.sh            0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off  S:on
mountnfs-bootclean.sh     0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off  S:on
mountnfs.sh               0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off  S:on
nfs-common                0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
nfs-kernel-server         0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
portmap                   0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
umountnfs.sh              0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
[mpenning@tsunami ~]$
```

To disable `portmap`, `nfs-common`, and `nfs-kernel-server` at all runlevels...

```
sudo chkconfig portmap off nfs-common off nfs-kernel-server off
```

Comment: chkconfig is a RH/RPM utility. You can install it under Debian, though it's not installed by default.  `update-rc.d` is probably the more appropriate tool to use.

Comment: yes Iinstalled it on my debian machine...